# Efficiently extracting set of unique values from lists within a dictionary

Tags: python, performance, extract, python-itertools

I have a data structure which looks like this:

```
{'A': [2, 3, 5, 6], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 7], 'C': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'D': [1, 4, 5, 6], 'E': [3, 4]}
```

Using Python, I need to extract this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Because I need a count of the distinct values for a mathematical equation further downstream.

Here is my current implementation, which works (complete code example):

```py
from itertools import chain

# Create som mock data for testing
dictionary_with_lists = {'A': [2, 3, 5, 6],
                         'B': [1, 2, 4, 7],
                         'C': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7],
                         'D': [1, 4, 5, 6],
                         'E': [3, 4]}

print(dictionary_with_lists)

# Output: 'A': [2, 3, 5, 6], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 7], 'C': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'D': [1, 4, 5, 6], 'E': [3, 4]}

# Flatten dictionary to list of lists, discarding the keys
list_of_lists = [dictionary_with_lists[i] for i in dictionary_with_lists]
print(f'list_of_lists: {list_of_lists}')

# Output: list_of_lists: [[2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], [1, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4]]

# Use itertools to flatten the list
flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
print(f'flat_list: {flat_list}')

# Output: flat_list: [2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4]

# Convert list to set to get only unique values
set_of_unique_items = set(flat_list)
print(f'set_of_unique_items: {set_of_unique_items}')

# Output: set_of_unique_items: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

While this works, but I suspect there might be a simpler and more efficient approach.

What would be a more efficient implementation which does not diminish code readability?

My real-world dictionary contains hundreds of thousands or millions of lists of arbitrary lengths.

Comment: why this `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` any condition or something?

Comment: @deadshot I need a count of the distinct items across all those lists for a mathematical equation further downstream in my data pipeline.

Comment: Improving working code is more appropriate for CodeReview than [so].

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for that advice. I was not aware of the existence of the CodeReview community. I will see if I can somehow migrate this question over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from itertools import chain

d = {'A': [2, 3, 5, 6], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 7], 'C': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'D': [1, 4, 5, 6], 'E': [3, 4]}
print(set(chain.from_iterable(d.values())))
```

**Output:**

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

An outsdider's point of view:

```
dict = {'A': [2, 3, 5, 6], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 7], 'C': [1, 3, 4, 5, 7], 'D': [1, 4, 5, 6], 'E': [3, 4]}

S = set()

for L in dict.values():
  S = S.union(set(L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = set()
for key in dictionary_with_lists:
    for val in dictionary_with_lists[key]:
        s.add(val)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to iterate over the values directly, instead of using the keys? You could also use the `set.update()` method to avoid having to add the elements of the list one by one.